# Page view constraints bug

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have set up a page view controller in swift with a scroll view and a view inside the scroll view. I made constraints for both of them but when I run the project on swiping left or right between the pages the view in the scroll view first comes a little bit smaller and then when the swipe is completed it expands.

Here is the problem:

[image]

Comment: It might not be the solution you are looking for, but have you tried setting the bounce horizontally property to true?

Comment: I tried but it seems its not the solution :/